# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: xamarin

I'm creating a multiplatform app in Xamarin with VS2017, and I'm getting this error from my UWP app.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. 

The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Threading.Thread, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at SS12.DataServices.SendScalar(String qString)
at SS12.ItemsPage.CheckUserLogin(String User, String Pwd)
at SS12.ItemsPage.<Login_Clicked>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Has anyone seen this before? What could be the cause?

Comment: What is the target framework of your UWP project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can target to build 16299 only this goes away magicamagica.

Answer (score 0):

UWP and Xamarin have recently supported that library.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

Be sure to set your minimum support to Fall creators update